# Haskell Webviewhs textfields and returns to Haskell

Tags: javascript, haskell, webview

I've discovered `webviewhs` and tried it recently. It just works and I think it can do what I need it to do. Samples are abundant, but I would need some pointers of Haskell experts.

```
{-# LANGUAGE
    OverloadedStrings
  , QuasiQuotes
#-}

import Data.Text
import Language.Javascript.JMacro
import qualified Graphics.UI.Webviewhs as WHS

main :: IO ()
main =
  WHS.withWindowLoop
    WHS.WindowParams
      { WHS.windowParamsTitle      = "webviewhs - How do I run some JavaScript inside the window?"
        -- This could be a localhost URL to your single-page application (SPA).
      , WHS.windowParamsUri        = ""
      , WHS.windowParamsWidth      = 800
      , WHS.windowParamsHeight     = 600
      , WHS.windowParamsResizable  = True
      , WHS.windowParamsDebuggable = True
      }
    -- This is the callback JavaScript can execute.
    (\ _window stringFromJavaScript -> print stringFromJavaScript) $
    -- This function runs every window loop.
    -- Return True to continue the loop or False to exit the loop.
    \ window -> do
      let string = "Hello from Haskell." :: Text
      -- runJavaScript returns either True on success or False on failure.
      WHS.runJavaScript
        window
        [jmacro|
          alert ("Yahoo! Alert windows, but little too persistent!");
          window.external.invoke("Hello from JavaScript.");
        |]
```

If I use the code above, the alert-dialog (test) keeps popping up. I would love to have it gone after `ok`. I also tried several times to get information (`document.getElementById`) from a sites' `input` field. Cannot get that to work. For me `webviewhs` is the missing link in Haskell and I would really like to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `WHS.withWindowLoop`. Referring to [the documentation](https://lettier.github.io/webviewhs/#v:withWindowLoop):

> Creates a window for you. Accepts a function that is called with each iteration of the window loop. If the accepted function returns `False`, the loop is exited and the window is destroyed. **If the accepted function returns `True`, the loop is continued** provided it can.

(my emphasis)

Note that the last parameter of `withWindowLoop` is invoked repeatedly until it returns `False`. However, you are always returning `True`, meaning that the dialog box is repeatedly opened without ever finishing the loop. I can see two ways out of this problem:

- Use `WHC.createWindow` instead; this function simply creates a window and returns it, without looping. This is the approach used [in the relevant example](https://github.com/lettier/webviewhs/blob/master/examples/how-do-i-open-an-alert-dialog.hs).
- Keep on using `withWindowLoop`, but return `False` instead of `True`. This will stop the loop immediately after one iteration.
- <s>If you really want to use `withWindowLoop`, then you could declare an `IORef` which is `True` at first, then changed to `False` after one iteration. That approach isn't very idiomatic though.</s> (Don't use this approach, it doesn't work, it actually launches the dialog box twice, and it's much more complicated than needed anyway)

Comment: Thanks. That works. Remaining question is to get info from a textfield using `getElementById`. That would already help me get forward with `webviewhs`.

Comment: @Madderote Are you asking that as a question, or simply making a comment about  what you have left to learn? If you're asking a question, it would be better to ask it as a completely new question and not write it as a comment.

Comment: Reading it now it seems like a new question. Will repost.

Comment: Thanks @Madderote! It doesn't look like your question is up yet, but I'll definitely have a look at it when it is.

Comment: @bradm: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55869718/haskell-webviewhs-getelementbyid-from-a-webpage ;-)