# Haskell Webviewhs getElementById from a webpage

Tags: javascript, sqlite, haskell

Still most potential for a GUI to Haskell for me, but missing some essential info in the examples, being a noob Haskeller. Assuming one of the examples:

```
{-
  webviewhs
  (C) 2018 David Lettier
  lettier.com
-}

{-# LANGUAGE
    OverloadedStrings
#-}

import qualified Graphics.UI.Webviewhs as WHS

main :: IO ()
main =
  WHS.createWindowAndBlock
    WHS.WindowParams
      { WHS.windowParamsTitle      = "webviewhs - How do I create a window and have it run itself?"
        -- This could be a localhost URL to your single-page application (SPA).
      , WHS.windowParamsUri        = "https://lettier.github.com"
      , WHS.windowParamsWidth      = 800
      , WHS.windowParamsHeight     = 600
      , WHS.windowParamsResizable  = True
      , WHS.windowParamsDebuggable = True
      }
```

This creates a window in which I can load a custom webpage. Assuming this webpage has a `<input type="text" id="mytext">` and there's a button next to it. Not that it matters but `<button type="submit" id="sendtohaskell">`. How would I go about getting the info in the textfield to Haskell by pressing the button? There's no example like that in the tutorial. For me it is the missing link to get info from a webapp, processing it in Haskell and returning it to eg. SQLite.

Comment: It's not missing from the tutorial. How to communicate between Haskell and JavaScript is literally in the next paragraph after the code you're quoting here on the [github page](https://github.com/lettier/webviewhs)

Comment: You should also take a look at the examples: https://github.com/lettier/webviewhs/tree/master/examples

Comment: @Cubic no its not. That does not create a window nor gets anything back. Sorry that I just don't see it here. Think my question is quite clear and that specific example is not available unfortunately.

Comment: @Michael Litchard: wouldn't have posted the question if I didn't try and tried all examples. It is a very specific question and documentation other than the examples on github are very limited to non-existent.

Comment: @Madderote Actually there is plenty of documentation at https://lettier.github.io/webviewhs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [github page](https://github.com/lettier/webviewhs) shows, you can receive data from JS with a callback, and execute arbitrary JS in the window from Haskell. This is enough to do any sort of communication you might want, here's an example that that executes some Haskell on a button press and then shows the result in the webpage:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings, QuasiQuotes #-}
module Main where

import System.Directory(getCurrentDirectory)
import Text.Printf
import Control.Monad(void)
import Language.Javascript.JMacro
import qualified Graphics.UI.Webviewhs as WHS
import qualified Data.Text as T

windowCallback window = do
  return True

handleJSRequest window request = void . WHS.runJavaScript window $ [jmacro|
  show_response `(printf "'Got response: %s'" request :: String)`
  |]

main :: IO ()
main = void $ do
  dir <- getCurrentDirectory
  WHS.withWindowLoop
    WHS.WindowParams
      { WHS.windowParamsTitle = "Test"
      , WHS.windowParamsUri = T.pack $ printf "file://%s/example.html" dir
      , WHS.windowParamsWidth = 800
      , WHS.windowParamsHeight = 600
      , WHS.windowParamsResizable = True
      , WHS.windowParamsDebuggable = True
      }
    handleJSRequest
    windowCallback
```

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function show_response(response) {
        document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = response;
      }
      function submit() {
        var value = document.getElementById('textbox').value;
        window.external.invoke(value)
      }
    </script>
    <input type="text" id="textbox"/>
    <input value="say hello" type="button" onclick="submit()"/>
    <p id="response"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

You should note though that the haskell webview library has only 2 commits, the last of which was more than 7 months ago, so it's not exactly being actively developed at the moment.

Comment: Thanks Cubic. Answered with exactly what I needed to know. Now I can comfortably concentrate on learning Haskell again 8)
By the way: thanks for the comments on the development. Have to say though that I actually like this one the best when it comes to Haskell GUIs.